# How to draw detected rectangle path on live camera feed using CAShapeLayer and UIBezeirPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cidetector

I am developing an application to detect rectangles in a live camera feed and highlight the detected rectangle. I did camera thing using `AVFoundation` and used below methods in order to do detect and highlight the detected rectangle.

```
var detector: CIDetector?;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    detector = self.prepareRectangleDetector();
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) { // re check this method

    // Need to shimmy this through type-hell
    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    // Force the type change - pass through opaque buffer
    let opaqueBuffer = Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer>.passUnretained(imageBuffer!).toOpaque()
    let pixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(opaqueBuffer).takeUnretainedValue()

    let sourceImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: nil)

    // Do some detection on the image
    self.performRectangleDetection(sourceImage);

    var outputImage = sourceImage

    // Do some clipping
    var drawFrame = outputImage.extent
    let imageAR = drawFrame.width / drawFrame.height
    let viewAR = videoDisplayViewBounds.width / videoDisplayViewBounds.height

    if imageAR > viewAR {
        drawFrame.origin.x += (drawFrame.width - drawFrame.height * viewAR) / 2.0
        drawFrame.size.width = drawFrame.height / viewAR
    } else {
        drawFrame.origin.y += (drawFrame.height - drawFrame.width / viewAR) / 2.0
        drawFrame.size.height = drawFrame.width / viewAR
    }

    //videoDisplayView is a GLKView which is used to display camera feed
    videoDisplayView.bindDrawable()
    if videoDisplayView.context != EAGLContext.currentContext() {
        EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(videoDisplayView.context)
    }

    // clear eagl view to grey
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glClear(0x00004000)

    // set the blend mode to "source over" so that CI will use that
    glEnable(0x0BE2);
    glBlendFunc(1, 0x0303);

    renderContext.drawImage(outputImage, inRect: videoDisplayViewBounds, fromRect: drawFrame);

    videoDisplayView.display();

}

func prepareRectangleDetector() -> CIDetector {

    let options: [String: AnyObject] = [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh];
    return CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeRectangle, context: nil, options: options);
}

func performRectangleDetection(image: CIImage){

    let resultImage: CIImage? = nil;

    if let detector = detector {

        // Get the detections
        let features = detector.featuresInImage(image, options: [CIDetectorAspectRatio:NSNumber(float:1.43)]);


        if features.count != 0{ // feature found

            for feature in features as! [CIRectangleFeature] {

                self.previewImageView.layer.sublayers = nil;

                let line: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer();
                line.frame = self.videoDisplayView.bounds;
                let linePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath();

                linePath.moveToPoint(feature.topLeft);
                linePath.addLineToPoint(feature.topRight);
                linePath.addLineToPoint(feature.bottomRight);
                linePath.addLineToPoint(feature.bottomLeft);
                linePath.addLineToPoint(feature.topLeft);
                linePath.closePath();

                line.lineWidth = 5.0;
                line.path = linePath.CGPath;
                line.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor;
                line.strokeColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x3399CC, alpha: 1.0).CGColor;

                // videoDisplayParentView is the parent of videoDisplayView and they both have same bounds
                self.videoDisplayParentView.layer.addSublayer(line);
             }    
         }                    
     }
}
```

I used `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath` to draw the rectangle. This is very very slow. Path gets visible after minutes.

Can Someone please help me to figure out why it is slow or let me know if I am doing something wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Or if there is some way easy than this I would like to know it too.

Comment: any infos on what you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you need to know, exactly. I have done detecting rectangle in a live video feed and i am getting correct points. Now I need to draw a rectangle on my live video feed using those 4 points . I used UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer to draw that rectangle. But it is very slow.

Comment: TL;DR .. ok .. thats what I didnt know that its slow until you edited..

Comment: Ah! sorry about that. Mistakenly I pressed post button before finish typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you get into the business of adding a sublayer to a GLKView it will be slow. The GLKView here refreshes multiple times every second (as it is in captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:.. method), the process of creating and adding the sublayer every time will not be able to keep up with.

A better way is to draw the path using CoreImage and compositing it over resultImage.